# Допустимы ли в литературе умышленные ошибки в прямой речи?

Tags: выбор-слов, прямая-речь

Допустимы ли в литературе намеренные ошибки и просторечия в прямой речи для подчеркивания характера, качеств отдельных действующих лиц? Например:

1) "Как думаешь, они нас видят?" - "Видют-видют".

2) "Народ, не стесняйся: все уплочено!"

Есть ли примеры из художественной литературы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вестимо, допустимы. Только почему Вы индивидуальную речь персонажа называете ошибкой?

Со стороны автора будет прямо-таки предательством по отношению к герою имманентное ему "видют" или "плотют" заменять каким-либо литературно нормированным словцом.  И - зачем?! Это ж речевая характеристика персонажа!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот всем этим некодифицированным формам самое место в художественной литературе.

См. подробнее:  **[Норма и некодифицированная речь](https://studme.org/1597012218398/literatura/norma_nekodifitsirovannaya_rech)**

---

[Александр Миронов. Русская удаль. Сборник рассказов.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=3LE8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT115&dq=%E2%80%93%20%D0%AD%D0%B9,%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0,%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83,%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80.%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB.%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F.%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0,%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B7...%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5.%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5,%20%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5!&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi59fyqo7zZAhWDLMAKHUEzBE8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]